# Server Request Interrupted on Heroku when using Busboy

Tags: node.js, express, busboy

I am using Busboy to transfer files in my Nodejs app since it supports chunked uploads. When the files are just small sized images upload is working fine but once I'm about uploading videos sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't work and all I keep seeing on my Heroku logs is

> H18-Server Request Interrupted.

This is quite draining.

Here is my code:

```
    path = require('path'),
    os = require('os'),
    fs = require('fs');
 
var Busboy = require('busboy');
 
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      var saveTo = path.join(os.tmpDir(), path.basename(fieldname));
      file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));
    });
    busboy.on('finish', function() {
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Connection': 'close' });
      res.end("That's all folks!");
    });
    return req.pipe(busboy);
  }
  res.writeHead(404);
  res.end();
}).listen(8000, function() {
  console.log('Listening for requests');
});
```

How can this be resolved?